# Extract Numeric Date Value from short Date Format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to convert short date format to numeric date format in SQL.

Here are the dates I am trying to convert:
16-Mar-20
18-Mar-20
12-Mar-20

I have seen many methods to re-format dates based on numeric numbers but I am working with a dataset which has varied date-types. To ensure smoothness, I wanted to know what's the way to convert these numbers to numeric date. Note that even if I extract the day month and year individually I could multiply them with respective values to get the dates. Here's what I have done: (Although I have tried multiple things but this is the one which has yielded me the closest result, Note that my end goal is to convert the date into numeric value)

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(`Start Date`, 'dd-MMM-yy') AS 'Date Numeric'
```

Here Start Date is formatted in the way I have mentioned above. (14-Mar-20).

Comment: The code looks like MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Cool, sure thanks for refining and informing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP is what you need, but first you have do transform your data to a Date

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`Start Date`, '%d-%b-%y'))
```

With

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE( "14-Mar-20", "%d-%b-%y"))
```

You get

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE( "14-Mar-20", "%d-%b-%y"))
1584144000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Unix timestamp, use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`Start Date`, 'dd-MMM-yy'))
```

Comment: I am getting this error: mysql error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP'

Comment: @Gorden Linoff UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-04-089 10:30:19') has only 1 parameter